# nested class variables python

Tags: python, nested-class

I'm trying to assign a variable in my inner class with the variable on the outer class.

```
class OUTER(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):        
        super (OUTER, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()
    def number (self):
        self.out = 50
    ...

    class INNER(QtGui.QLCDNumber)
        in = OUTER.out  #error: NameError: name 'OUTER' is not defined

        @pyqtSlot()
        def some_func(self):
            self.display(self.in)
```

I'm getting an error

```
NameError: name 'OUTER' is not defined.
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: *I'm trying to assign a variable in my inner class with the variable on the outer class* .... Ok. Please continue

Comment: @BhargavRao The error is in this line: `in = OUTER.out  #error: NameError: name 'OUTER' is not defined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this.

OUTER is not defined until the entire outer class declaration is finished. Class bodies are executable code; they are executed at definition time. When the body is defined, it is allocated to the name, but until then the name does not exist.

That is one of the reasons why nesting classes is rarely a good idea in Python. The inner class does not get any special access to the outer class, so there isn't really any reason to nest them at all.

Plus, I've just noticed that you are trying to refer to an instance variable via a class. That can't ever work. `OUTER.out` does not exist, only instances of `OUTER` have an `out` attribute. (What would the value of `OUTER.out` even be?)